# Why isn't fontspec activating the +zero feature in Libertinus Serif?

Tags: fontspec, libertine, opentype, number

The documentation for the font Libertinus Serif notes that the OpenType tag `zero` should enable slashed zeroes.  However, when adding this feature in `fontspec`, it does not appear to work.  Here is my (non-working) minimal example, which produces 2020 without slashed zeroes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={+zero}]{Libertinus Serif}
\begin{document}
    2020
\end{document}
```

Comment: works fine for me with lualatex on a current texlive.

Comment: Works for me with xelatex too